# Zipping only files in Python

Tags: python

So I create several files in some temp directory dictated by NamedTemporaryFile function.

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile( zipPath, mode='w' )
for file in files:
    with NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+b', bufsize=-1, prefix='tmp') as tempFile:
       tempPath = tempFile.name
    with open(tempPath, 'w') as f:
       write stuff to tempPath with contents of the variable 'file'
    zf.write(tempPath)

zf.close()
```

When I use the path of these files to add to a zip file, the temp directories themselves get zipped up.
When I try to unzip, I get a series of temp folders, which eventually contain the files I want.
(i.e. I get the folder Users, which contains my user_id folder, which contains AppData...).

Is there a way to add the files directly, without the folders, so that when I unzip, I get the files directly?  Thank you so much!

Comment: From python 2.7, you can use ZipFile as a context manager: `with zipfile.ZipFile(zipPath, mode='w') as zf`

Comment: I'm stuck with 2.6.6.  Otherwise, I would have used it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving the arcname:

```
from os import path

zf = zipfile.ZipFile( zipPath, mode='w' )
for file in files:
    with NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+b', bufsize=-1, prefix='tmp') as tempFile:
       tempPath = tempFile.name
    with open(tempPath, 'w') as f:
       write stuff to tempPath with contents of the variable 'file'
    zf.write(tempPath,arcname=path.basename(tempPath))

zf.close()
```

Using `os.path.basename` you can get the file's name from a path. According to [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) documentation, the default value for arcname is filename without a drive letter and with leading path separators removed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `arcname` parameter to `zf.write`:

```
zf.write(tempPath, arcname='Users/mrb0/Documents/things.txt')
```

Without knowing more about your program, you may find it easier to get your `arcname` from the `file` variable in your outermost loop rather than deriving a new name from `tempPath`.